# Swift: Mac OSX: How to authenticate to write/read in firebase server with my app

Tags: swift, macos, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
import Cocoa
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAuth

class LoginViewController: NSViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var idTextField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pwTextField: NSTextField!

    @IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    }

    @IBAction func registerButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.

        FirebaseApp.configure()


        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let test = ["hi":"real", "he":"sh"]
        ref.child("hi/really").setValue(test)
    }

}
```

This is a simple code of the login/registration page of my application. But the login itself is not what is really important to me. (In fact, I do know that there is a user login authentication feature in firebase) In the viewDidLoad() function, I have configured the firebase server and am trying to add some kind of random list to the realtime database. Of course, I have installed the pod and google plist, so it works!!! YEAH!!!

But it works only when the rules of the database are like this.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

I am trying to publish this app, which means the server should not be accessible by any random people. But if I turn the rules to this

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

or this which is [provided by firebase tutorials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart?hl=ko)

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I get the message:

> permission denied

I looked up many StackOverflow questions and other tutorials, but they didn't have the answer for me.

So how can I make my swift MAC OSX app to write on my firebase database without setting the database public to everyone?

Comment: Your code is not signing the user in, so it makes sense that your write gets rejected if your rules require that the user is signed in. Did you try [signing in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start) yet?

Comment: Oooohh... It looks like you can read my mind :) Actually I have tried signing in and creating user with email and password, and succeeded it. But the problem doesn't seem to be solved. I think I am missing a step to use the logined user to write. If possible, could you leave a short sample code of signing in as a user and additionally writing something as the user? I will really appreciate your help!

Comment: The code in your question shows no sign-in, so it's hard to say if you're doing it right. Instead of asking me to write sample code, I suggest you try to implement what the documentation I linked earlier shows, and edit your question to include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you still have problems.